# an algorithm question(Google code jam 2011 Arabia 2011)

Tags: algorithm

There is a pool of numbers which are arbitrary decimal fractions from the interval (0, 1). In the first round of the game the middle third of the interval disappears, and the numbers from this interval are eliminated from the pool. In the next rounds the middle thirds of each of the remaining intervals disappear. In the first round the the interval [1/3, 2/3] is eliminated and in the second round the two intervals [1/9, 2/9] and [7/9, 8/9] are eliminated, and so on. The endpoints of each removed interval are removed as well.

Your role is to sort the pool of numbers in the order that they are eliminated. If some numbers are never eliminated, list them last. In case of a tie, list the smaller numbers first.

```
int getRound(double lb, double ub, double val){
double lb2 = (2*lb + ub)/3.0;
double ub2 = (lb +2*ub)/3.0;
if((lb2<=val)&&(val<=ub2)) return 1;
else if (val<lb2){
    return 1+getRound(lb,lb2,val);
}
else return getRound(ub2,ub,val)+1;
```

}

```
int main(){
    int N;
    cin >> N;

    vector <pair<int,double> > vp;
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++){           
        double x;
        cin >> x;
        int r = getRound(0,1.0,x);
        //if(r>25) r = 25;
        pair <int,double> pid;
        pid.first = r;
        pid.second = x;
        vp.push_back(pid);
    }
    sort(vp.begin(),vp.end());
    for(int j=0;j<vp.size();j++){
        cout << vp[j].second << endl;
    }
}
```

Let me explain the above code a little bit. 
The integer **N** is the length of test array.

Can anyone help me check the above code? Or give me some special cases that fail the above code? I do believe there exist some special cases.

Thanks,

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set

Answer (score 0):

Your logic looks right, but I'd be concerned that there may be cases where `getRound` may go into an infinite loop.  I would also return 1 if `ub - lb < 0.1**12`.  That will prevent floating point errors from getting you into an infinite loop.  However you have the hard coded constant.

I might instead go the path of taking `val` and multiplying by 3 in each round, then subtracting 1, then seeing whether it is in the range `0 < val < 1`.  If you do that then you'll want to limit the number of rounds you can go.  The advantage of this is that you avoid roundoff errors on dividing by 3, which can result in logical mistakes in processing of numbers that you can represent.  With multiplying by 3 the only possible logical mistakes are due to round-off in generating your starting number.